# how to get unformated text in fckeditor in javascript

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

i want to get non formated text from fckedittor
i want the plain text as entrterd by the user not the encoded

Answer (score 0):

There is there, top left as I recall, a "view source" button. Is this what you wanted ?